# Randomly Distribute Specific Values Without Repetition Using Excel

Tags: excel, random, distribution

I need to *randomly distribute 1000 customer phone numbers* to *25 Customer Care Agents without repetition* using Excel.

I have tried using **RANDBETWEEN** function but the phone numbers are non-consecutive while numbers were repeated.

Can this be achieved on Excel?

Comment: I don't suppose you could just put `=CEILING.MATH(25*RAND(),1)` in a column next to your data? This will then put a random number between 1 and 25 next to your data. You can then copy-and-paste these values as values before sorting on this column.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the phone numbers in `A1:A1000` then put this formula in B1

`=RAND()`

and copy all the way down to row 1000 (you can do that easily by double clicking on the "fill-handle" in B1 - the black "+" you see if you put the cursor on the bottom right of the cell).

Now select both columns A and B and sort by column B - that will sort your phone numbers randomly, so just allocate the top 40 to the first Agent, the next 40 to the next agent etc.